# Converting a String into a list of computing steps: Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, java

I'd like to ask wether there is a way to evaluate javascript terms multiple times without needing to parse a term over and over and over again.

Say, you want to evaluate

```
var1/var2+Math.sqrt(var3)
```

20 times a second.

This could be problematic when using

```
ScriptEngine.eval(string)
```

continueously, because you would have to replace "var1" every single time, then parse it and then let the script engine figure out the order of operations you want to perform.

Is there any alternative way?
Say, you have a configuration file in which a user gets to specify variables which increase and decrease after certain events.

You have a fixed term which javascript needs to process and the user also gets to define, but the variables change.

So is there a way to save a term as a list of operations (which internally speaking, it is) into which you only need to input the variables?
So basically, is there a way around parsing and creating an operation order over and over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could evaluate the expression wrapped in a function:

```js
var expression = "var1/var2+Math.sqrt(var3)";
eval( 'function myTest(var1,var2,var3){ return ' + expression + "}" );
console.log(myTest, myTest(1, 2, 9) );
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for a for loop.

```
var x = //number of time you want to run
for (i = 0; i < x; i++) { 
  //code...
}
```

or a while loop

```
while (condition is true) {
    //code...
}
```

Just switch out the variables as needed to adjust how long the process runs. Or really anything else you need to adjust.